# Need to remove duplicates from a table and create a distinct or unique view

Tags: sql, select

I have a table T1 that has redundant data

```
SID  Date  LinkName           
S1   12      Link1           
S1   21      Link1           
S1   12      Link2           
S2   21      Link2          
S2   12      Link2         
S2   21      Link3
S3   12      Link1          
S3   21      Link2         
S3   12      Link3
```

Date field is any other field which is in table. but it should not be used

Now, using select statement, i want to create a view which shows data as per unique link.
Like here, for Link1, S1 and S3 are there, for Link3 , S2 and S3 are there. etc/

Final View

```
SID LinkName                   
S1  Link1
S1  Link2
S2  Link2
S2  Link3
S3  Link3
S3  Link1   
S3  Link2
```

How to create this view using Select statement. Pls advise.

Comment: `select distinct ...`

Comment: I am unable to create view using distinct. Pretty new to SQL
I need SID in front and LinkName at last column

Comment: What DB engine do you use? Try `select distinct SID, LinkName from your_table` or `select SID, LinkName from your_table group by SID, LinkName`

Comment: that worked. thanks